# Ansible dynamic include_vars and include_tasks by OS

Tags: dynamic, ansible, operating-system, selection

Using ansible to bootstrap and maintain multiple servers, with different OSes. I would like to have my own set of roles, every one of them with the same tasks/main.yml, something like this:

```
---
- name: EXIT - not supported OS found
  fail:
    msg: "Unsupported OS {{ ansible_distribution }} {{ ansible_distribution_version }} ({{ ansible_distribution_major_version }})"
  when: 
    - ansible_distribution != "CentOS" or ansible_distribution_major_version != "8"
    - ansible_distribution != "Debian" or ansible_distribution_version != "10"
    - ansible_distribution != "Ubuntu" or ansible_distribution_version != "20.04"

- name: "Load OS family specific variables - {{ ansible_os_family }}_family.yml"
  include_vars: 
    file: "vars/{{ ansible_os_family }}_family.yml"
  ignore_errors: true
- name: "Load distribution specific variables - {{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
  include_vars: 
    file: "vars/{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
  ignore_errors: true
- name: "Load distribution major version specific variables - {{ ansible_distribution }}_{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.yml"
  include_vars: 
    file: "vars/{{ ansible_distribution }}_{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.yml"
  ignore_errors: true
- name: "Load distribution version specific variables - {{ ansible_distribution }}_{{ ansible_distribution_version }}.yml"
  include_vars: 
    file: "vars/{{ ansible_distribution }}_{{ ansible_distribution_version }}.yml"
  ignore_errors: true

- name: Running common tasks for any distribution any version - common.yml
  include_tasks: common.yml
  ignore_errors: true
- name: "Running tasks for OS family - {{ ansible_os_family }}_family.yml"
  include_tasks: "{{ ansible_os_family }}_family.yml"
  ignore_errors: true
- name: "Running tasks for distribution - {{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
  include_tasks: "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
  ignore_errors: true
- name: "Running tasks for {{ ansible_distribution }} {{ ansible_distribution_version }} ({{ ansible_distribution_major_version }})"
  include_tasks: "{{ lookup('first_found', possible_files) }}"
  vars:
    possible_files:
      - "{{ ansible_distribution }}_{{ ansible_distribution_version }}.yml"
      - "{{ ansible_distribution }}_{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.yml"
  ignore_errors: true
```

The first task will precheck all supported OSes, and stop the execution if the OS is not supported by the role.

With this I can define variables on different levels and later it can be overridden. For example, if a variable is defined in RedHat_family.yml then it will be accessible for CentOS 7 and CentOS 8, but if it is redefined in CentOS_8.yml then only for CentOS 8 it will have another value. At the same time it is not necessary to exist all .ymls for all supported OSes and versions because of `ignore_errors: true`. This part is working.

The problem is in the tasks section. This section is not wotking.

```
fatal: [myserver]: FAILED! => {"reason": "Could not find or access 'playbooks/common.yml' on the Ansible Controller."}
```

Include_tasks do not support ignore_errors. I would like to group tasks in common tasks, OS family tasks, distribution tasks, distribution version tasks, and every one of them can exist or not exist. How can I achieve this kind of functionality? Is there any better solution for this kind of dynamic load of OS dependent variables and tasks?

Thank you,

Comment: As I say, the include_vars portion is working. Maybe it does not need the ignore_errors: true, but is working aniway.

Comment: I tryed a play with include_vars without ignore_errors: true on Debian 10 and ansible 2.9.9. The play was aborted with error if the file does not exists.